# When is the next Ubuntu community wallpaper contest?

Tags: desktop-background, community, photo, design

Does anybody know when the next Ubuntu community wallpaper contest will be?

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak), the contest is already open for submissions and will close on 26 September 2016. Submit your wallpaper at https://www.flickr.com/groups/ubuntu-fcs-1610/. Read more about the guidelines at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFreeCultureShowcase, which I will copy and paste here for your convenience:

> #### Wallpaper
>
> We're looking for photographic wallpapers: lovely backgrounds that
>   greet the user on Ubuntu's welcome screen and at login, and provide a
>   main color for the Unity Dash! We're also looking for an illustrative
>   wallpaper that plays off the theme of the current development release
>   (for 16.10, that's Yakkety Yak [1]).
>
> - Images shouldn’t be too busy and filled with too many shapes and colors, a similar tone throughout is a good rule of thumb.
> - A single point of focus, a single area that draws the eye into the image, can also help you avoid something too cluttered.
> - The left and top edges are home to Ubuntu’s Launcher and Panel so be careful to consider how your images look in place so as not to clash
>     with the user interface.
> - Try them out on your own desktop; see how they feel. Try your image at different aspect ratios to make sure something important isn’t
>     cropped out on smaller/ larger screens at different resolutions.
> - Take a look at the wallpapers guidance on the Ubuntu Wiki regarding the size of images. Our target resolution is 3840 x 2400. This might
>     result in a centered, 1080x1920 cropped image on Ubuntu phones, so
>     keep this in mind!
> - Break all the rules except the resolution one! :)

[1]: I have changed "for 16.04, that's Xenial Xerus" in the wiki to "for 16.10, that's Yakkety Yak".